# Occasional Error Connecting to Pymssql (Error 20009)

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I have used `pymssql` in Python for well over a year with no issues. Suddenly, I began getting this error:

```
MSSQLDatabaseException: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
```

I only get the issue about 1 out of every 3 attempts to connect via Python. I am using a Mac (Mojave 10.14.6). I typically use SQLPro for MSSQL for queries as well and am having the same problem there (though much less frequently). I don't believe it is a problem with my credentials or the SQL Server because 1) it does work some and 2) I also attempted to connect via a Windows machine with no issue.

I have also attempted this, as suggested to test connection

`tsql -H sqlserverhost -p 1433 -U user -P password -D tempdb`

but get the following even though I have never had trouble connecting in over a year:

```
    Server name not found in configuration files.
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20013 (severity 2):
    Unknown host machine name.
Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

How does this happen and how can I resolve quickly to get back up and running consistently?

Comment: i think you need to check your azure subscription

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Not sure what you mean by "check" but my azure subscription has not changed.